# Convert list to DataFrame with a specific column (has no name) as a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list that I will generate a dataframe with values that have zero on the right like `1.257000`, so I need to generate it as a string because as a number these zeros on the right disappear, how should I proceed?

My attempts to identify column 5 (where the values are):

```
b = [
     ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3', 'string 4', 1.257000, 'string 6'],
     ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3', 'string 4', 1.546440, 'string 6']
    ]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(b, dtype={5: str})
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(b, dtype={'5': str})
```

Current results in Column 5 using only `pd.DataFrame(b)`:

```
1.257
1.54644
```

Expected result in Column 5:

```
1.257000
1.546440
```

Additional comment after response generated by [Zaero Divide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72580049/11462274):

The numbers in my case can vary in size, it can be `1.230` `1.23000` `1.2300000`, so I can't format by specifying an equal final number of characters for all after creating the DataFrame.

Comment: You'll need to explicitly convert the 5th element of each iterable in that list to a string before you feed them into the DataFrame.

Comment: Hi @Xelvoz I understand, I imagined that as we can generate DataFrame via CSV already modifying string, so there would also be a way to do this generating from a list. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Unfortunately, the `converters` parameter is only available in the `pd.read_csv` function since it helps the parser know which column types pandas need to infer and which it needs to uphold. Since your data is already in a list format, then it is assumed it is already parsed and processed to fit your type needs.

Comment: Perfect @Xelvoz I understand, could you create an answer with this explanation so that I can close the question since there is no solution and maybe in the future other people can search for this same question? Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear for me what you want to do. Do you want to convert the column into decimal notation with a given number of decimals? If so, most likely it is a duplicated question, as it is a quite typical thing.

Comment: Hi @ZaeroDivide, I actually need to convert numbers with decimals with trailing zeros, but Xelvoz was explained that it is not possible, only using the ```pd.read_csv```. Thanks for support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the output of b is:

```
[
 ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3', 'string 4', 1.257, 'string 6'], 
 ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3', 'string 4', 1.54644, 'string 6']
]
```

Instantly, those 0s no longer exist.

---

If you instead had a string/file that looked like:

```
string 1,string 2,string 3,string 4,1.257000,string 6
string 1,string 2,string 3,string 4,1.546440,string 6
```

Then it could be read like you want:

```
file = """string 1,string 2,string 3,string 4,1.257000,string 6
string 1,string 2,string 3,string 4,1.546440,string 6"""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(file), dtype=str, header=None)
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  string 1  string 2  string 3  string 4  1.257000  string 6
1  string 1  string 2  string 3  string 4  1.546440  string 6
```

Comment: Perfect, I managed to understand perfectly the root of the problem, in fact it would be completely impossible since the problem already starts even before trying to create the DataFrame. Thanks!

Comment: @DigitalFarmer I added a section showing how to read a file/file-like object like this and keep trailing zeros~

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the trailing zeroes, you can use format string, for instance:

```
>>> df[4].transform(lambda x: f"{x:0.6f}")
0    1.257000
1    1.546440
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

If you want to apply to all representations:

```
>>> pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.8f}'.format
>>> df[4]
0   1.25700000
1   1.54644000
Name: 4, dtype: float64
```

**Edit** As long as numbers are introduced as numbers, the trailing zeros are automatically removed. They should be introduced as string. There is no conversion from `float` to `str` that will bring back the original number of zeros, because for python they were never really there

Comment: Hi @ZaeroDivide The problem with this option is that you need to make sure that the numbers will always have the same amount of characters on final string, I think it's important to add this note to the answer. (For my specific case it wouldn't work but your answer is a good tip for those who can format after creating the DataFrame)  → I can't trust that all correct values will always have 6 numbers exactly, for example.

Comment: Ah! You want to have the "original" number. of digits

Comment: It's just that the original numbers can actually be ```1.230``` or ```1.230000000``` for example, so in my specific case I can't format them all to have the same amount of characters, but please don't delete your answer, keep it, because it might help other people.

Comment: The problem is that in your list the numbers already are stripped out of the zeroes. It is only possible if your list is NOT with floats. If you ask python to show `b` it already has removed the zeros. Only if you use strings instead it would be possible to manipulate the data

Comment: In fact, as Xelvoz said, I'll have to convert the values from the original list to string before creating the DataFrame. Unfortunately the ```dtype string``` option is not for list, only for ```read_csv```

Comment: the original list, as soon as you introduce it like `1.25000` for python it is `1.25`. AFAIK you cannot recover that information. unless you create it like `'1.25000'`